# Is it possible in Neo4j in the RETURN clause to aggregate boolean values by true or false?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Ok, I'm trying to figure out if there is a query that can give me something similar to the following:

```
MATCH (practiceTest:PracticeTest)
RETURN count(distinct practiceTest.passed===true), count(distinct practiceTest.passed===false)
```

I'm aware that this query does not work, but I'm curious if there is a way to do something similar to this, without having to write the following:

```
MATCH (practiceTest:PracticeTest)
WHERE practiceTest.passed = true
RETURN count(distinct practiceTest);

MATCH (practiceTest:PracticeTest)
WHERE practiceTest.passed = false
RETURN count(distinct practiceTest);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

another approach

```
MATCH (p:PracticeTest)
WITH COLLECT(p.passed) AS results
RETURN SIZE([result IN results WHERE result=true]) AS num_passed,
       SIZE([result IN results WHERE result=false]) AS num_failed
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You could count the result of a `CASE` statement when a practiceTest is `true` and then count again when the reulst is false.

```
MATCH (p:PracticeTest)
RETURN count(CASE WHEN p.passed = true THEN 1 END) AS num_true, count(CASE WHEN p.passed = false THEN 1 END) AS num_false
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The following query is pretty efficient in time and space. It only makes one aggregating function invocation, creates only one list, and only makes one pass through that list:

```
MATCH (p:PracticeTest)
WITH COLLECT(p.passed) AS data
WITH data, REDUCE(ps = 0, x IN data | CASE WHEN x THEN ps+1 ELSE ps END) AS passes
RETURN passes, SIZE(data)-passes AS fails
```

*NOTE: This query does not count `p` nodes that have no `passed` property. Also, the `passed` value must be a boolean.*

Comment: well, this works under the assumption that you only have 'true' and  'false' as  values, not nulls

Comment: True. Added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Returning counts of boolean values

If all you want to do is return the count of how many passed or failed, you could use the following:

```
MATCH (practiceTest:PracticeTest)
RETURN practiceTest.passed AS PassedTest,
  count(practiceTest) AS Frequency
```

which will return something like

```
╒════════════╤═══════════╕
│"PassedTest"│"Frequency"│
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│true        │17682      │
├────────────┼───────────┤
│false       │27152      │
└────────────┴───────────┘
```

### Converting boolean to 1/0

If you wanted to convert True/False into 1/0 as some of the replies suggested, you can convert the boolean to an integer.

In Neo4j v4.3+, the [toInteger() function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.3/functions/scalar/#functions-tointeger) converts a boolean to 1/0. If you're on an earlier version, you can use [apoc.convert.toInteger()](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.convert/apoc.convert.toInteger/), but be aware that function is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0.